# Which boot menu option in boot manager do I need to select?

Tags: windows-7

When I turn on my PC, the boot manager displays boot menu options and asks me to select from among SATA HDD, SATA ODD or Network Boot.  What do these options refer to, and which do I choose?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're going to want SATA HDD. This is the hard disk drive of your computer, and is where your operating system and files are stored.

The "SATA ODD" is your Optical Disk Drive. You would boot to this if you wanted to launch an OS or program from a CD.

The Network Boot is not usually something a home user would need to do, as it is usually saved for operating system deployment or other enterprise things, in my experience. So you can ignore it for now.